# Complex analysis find the laurent series, is my working out correct?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, education, laurent-series

I am posting this on behalf of a friend, she just wants confirmation  if her working out is correct.

[Answer of working out image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b3xi.jpg)

[revised working out answer image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PnCM.jpg)

Any input is much appreciated

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The denominator changes abruptly from $1-z$ to $1-(z-1) = 2-z$ with no explanation.  Is that two separate problems?

Given the region of convergence, I would assume the denominator should have been $2-z$ originally.   Under that assumption...

The final series converges in $|z-1|< 1$ and diverges for $|z-1|>1$, so it's the wrong region.

Comment: I really appreciate your input, sorry i am not familiar with the nomenclature of math, and English is my friend second language, so i am conveying back to her as much as i can, however, I have provided a second revised answer if you wouldn't mind taking a look to confirm it validity. thanks again.